# MVC routing is using parameter as view name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

***Further Information added below***

When using the following "RedirectToAction" (which produces the following URL) I get:

```
**The view 'searchterm' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/browse/searchterm.aspx
~/Views/browse/searchterm.ascx
~/Views/Shared/searchterm.aspx
~/Views/Shared/searchterm.ascx
~/Views/browse/searchterm.cshtml
~/Views/browse/searchterm.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/searchterm.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/searchterm.vbhtml**
```

Action generating the request:

```
public ActionResult Action(string id)
{
    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)))
    {
        string SearchTerm = id;
        return RedirectToAction("Products", new { SearchString = SearchTerm, Layout = "Row" });
    }
    return View();
}
```

URL:http://localhost:52006/browse/Products?SearchString=searchterm&Layout=Row

RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
       "Default", // Route name
       "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });

    routes.MapRoute(
       "Admin", // Route name
       "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = "" });
}
```

Products Controller:
    public ActionResult Products(string SearchString, string Layout = "Grid")
    {
        ViewBag.Layout = Layout;
        return View(SearchString);
    }

***further information***

**urls that end up going through the "products" action and being processed:**

```
http://localhost:52006/Browse/Products?Layout=Row#
```

- interesting because it shows that the parameters are not what is throwing the routing off

  http://localhost:52006/Browse/Products

**urls that end up looking for an action with name = SearchString:**

`http://localhost:52006/Browse/Products?Search=acolyte&Layout=Row` - interesting because it shows that the order of the parameters is not throwing the routing off/ it isn't just grabbing the first parameter as the action to look for.

```
http://localhost:52006/Browse/Products?Layout=Row&Search=acolyte
```

Comment: have you tried to use redirect base_url();?

Comment: I don't understand? Can you give an example.

Comment: instead of return RedirectAction use this "return redirect(base_url('path_to_redirect'));"

Comment: "redirect" doesn't exist?

Comment: there's also no reason why redirecttoaction doesn't work here.... but for soe reason it ends up looking for a view with a name = SearchString

Comment: Interestingly if i remove the search string parameter it works( though obviously without passing the search string to the action)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

through a combination of checking all routes included their areas and the route registration for the areas were correct i fixed this issue.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what you did to answer this question, as in what code you created to make this happen, how you fixed your original problem, etc, etc.

Comment: If  i'm honest i don't really remember , it was a while a go and i was hoping that closing some open questions mght permit me to ask questions again.

Comment: Yeah, I get it, the issue is that your answer appeared in another queue for possible "low quality answers" due to you answering an old question, so, the problem is that by answering your own question with a very undetailed answer, you now put yourself in a predicament of sorts